# Different tf versions have impact on the inference

Tags: tensorflow, version, inference

there, I trained a deeplab_v3+ using tf1.12 (py3.6) and run the inference using tf1.10(py3.6). However, the inference results are extremely bad (the segmentation outputs are all black). BTW, the inference works well based on the same environment as the training phase. Does the tf version influence the inference results? If not, what are the other reasons for the corrupted inference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running the inference of DeepLab and loading the model from .ckpt, the version of tf does not impact on the results. The reason for the bad inference results is that the "decoder_output_stride" is not set well.